# Capslock remapped with Tweak Tool. Keyboard shortcuts not working on Startup

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, compiz, restart, gnome-tweak-tool

I used the gnome-tweak-tool to remap my Capslock key as a super key. Shortcut keys involving the super key do not work upon system restart.

(However my keyboard shortcuts under launchers for things like the terminal [which for me is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd>] still work. Also, scripts that I made in AutoKey which use the super key still work for me)

To get a shortcut key to work again I have to go into the CompizConfig Settings Manager and disable then re-enable the key combination. Alternatively (and what I've been doing now), I can log out and log back in to the computer and all the shortcut keys involving super will be working.

Does anybody how I can get the keyboard shortcuts to work on startup?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I set capslock to be "an additional super" but it makes the original super (the windows icon on my keyboard) not work by itself. It does seem that using it as a modifier still works (e.g. Windows-S).

Comment: Settings capslock as "An Additional Super" worked fine for me (I don't have a windows key on this keyboard, IBM Model M)